# JQ Tree Show Only Selected Nodes With Their Parent On Button Click

Tags: jquery, jqtree

I have to show only selected nodes and parents, and hide rest nodes when a button is clicked. Only nothing happens when I click the button.

The jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/375emow0/

The code with commenting
    start on button click
    $('button[name="psychTree-selected"]').click( function(node) {

```
get the selected nodes
nodesSelected = $('#psychTree').tree('getSelectedNodes');

create an array for shown nodes
nodeIdsToStay = [];

walk through selected nodes
nodesSelected.forEach( function(node) {
var path = $('#psychTree').tree('getData');
path.forEach(function(n) {
if (nodeIdsToStay.indexOf(n)===-1) {
nodeIdsToStay.push(n);
}
})
})

hide the nodes not in the array
$('#psychTree').find('li').each( function(){
if ( nodeIdsToStay.indexOf(this.id) === -1 ) {
$(this).hide();
}
})
})
```

I know how to hide the selected nodes but apparently non selected nodes do not have an identifiable class for me to search and hide by http://jsfiddle.net/tom1nkfr/

```
`$('button[name="psychTree-selected"]').click( function() {`
`$('#psychTree').find('.jqtree-selected').each( function(){`
`$(this).hide();`
`})`
`})`
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question/error you're trying to resolve or are you hoping someone will do your work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend a simpler approach - it looks like you're trying to find all the nodes that are selected, push those into an `array`, then iterating over the entire jsTree and hiding any nodes *not* in the `array` you created. Instead, leverage the CSS classes that jsTree is already applying to selected nodes and just hide all those that don't have it.

Simplified JS:

```
$('button[name="psychTree-selected"]').click(function() {
  $('#psychTree li.jqtree_common').each(function(index,elem){
    if(!$(elem).hasClass('jqtree-folder') && !$(elem).hasClass('jqtree-selected')){
        $(elem).hide();
    }
  });
})
```

Still triggered on your button click, but now it iterates through all the tree nodes and hides any that are (1) not selected and (2) not parent/folder nodes.

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbwjau5m/

Comment: Wow thanks. I don't know why I didn't think of just using the classes. I mean I used the class to show only selected. I make things too complicated.

Comment: @ChiemiSayuri - great, glad to hear. If my answer suffices, please accept it.